# webView: decidePolicyForNavigationAction: request: frame: decisionListener: called multiple times

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, webkit

I am using the following code to load a url in my webview but it is called multiple times and my application crashes.

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id )listener
{

    [[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:request];
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `[listener use]` instead, to tell your webview to handle clicked URL.

Comment: Just remove your [[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:request]; and put [listener use];

Comment: is it possible to identify that a particular link or button or some web element is clicked on a web page?

Comment: What you mean by 'particular'? URL? DOM object? Ask another question with some details.

Comment: actually i want to perform some action when a user clicks on a button on a web page but i am not able to identify the user click in my code...is it possible?pls provide some sample code

Comment: This is exactly what the delegate's method in your question is for :)

Comment: When user clicks on any href element this method is called. The button though, may be a form as well. Without a html code of your button it's hard to answer your question.

Comment: ya i got ur point thx 4 the info its really helpful n ya 1 mor thing this method is sometimes called 2 times even though i clicked the link only once and displays the same actionInformation.

Comment: if i want to load a differnt url when above delegate method is called  using                                                      [[myWebView mainFrame] loadRequest:request]; app again crashes

Comment: DO NOT register your custom scheme with `[WebView registerURLSchemeAsLocal]`, otherwise decidePolicyForNavigationAction will not see the redirection.